# VM image vs Phyical server image?

Tags: virtual-machines, disk-image, physical-environment

I often hear its easy  to create the image of one VM and setup it another VM(even instance types are of different types) than creating the image on physical server. In fact one of the devops guy in the past told me image from physical server can not be created . Is that true ?

My understanding is that image will be created from disk in both cases either in case of VM or physical server. Is n't it ? Then why image of physical server can't be created or difficult to create  than creating the image from VM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use P2V utility (physical to virtual) to make a vm image and import it into your vm cluster.

Why do you think image of a physical server is hard to create? There is native utility does that, there are 3rd party utilities does that. Acronis, Veeam, Symantec and so on, they all can image physical and virtual servers

Comment: I have edited from question. Can you please reread it. Actually I am not asking how to copy the image from physical server to virtual server.

Answer (score 0):

An image of a physical server can be made and imported to your hypervisor. There a huge suite of tools that do this per Root Loop's answer. This is a good summary:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical-to-Virtual

Of course, in production, you typically want to keep software the same. It would be helpful to know what type of migration you require as well as what technologies you will be utilizing.

Edit: It is difficult to isolate operating data that any application needs vs OS system files. This is the main concern when you attempt a P2V migration. If you have a suite of tools that you can bundle where only your data changes, look into a container tech.